# Use Lagrange method to solve the constrained OP $\max_{x_{1}, x_{2}} 2x_{1} + 3 x_{2}$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

subject to $\sqrt{x_{1}} + \sqrt{x_{2}} = 5$.

I set up the Lagrangian first $\wedge (x_{1},x_{2}, \lambda) = 2 x_{1} + 3 x_{2} + \lambda\left ( 5 - \sqrt{x_{1}} - \sqrt{x_{2}} \right )$.

Then obtain the following first-order conditions:

$$\frac{\partial \wedge }{\partial x_{1}} = 2 - \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{x_{1}}} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \wedge }{\partial x_{2}} = 3 - \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{x_{2}}} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \wedge }{\partial \lambda} = 5 - \sqrt{x_{1}} - \sqrt{x_{2}}  = 0$$

Then I solve the above equations and find that $x_{1}=9$, $x_{2} = 4$, and $\lambda = 12$.

However the answer says that for the optimal solution $x_{1}=0$ and $x_{2}=25$.

I am not sure how they find this. Also, how do I check the *constraint qualification* the proper way?

For *CQ*, how do I show that the constraint is full rank?

I have $$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x_{1}}} & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x_{2}}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I am not sure how to infer that the Jacobian matrix is full rank.

Comment: You found $\min\limits_{x_1,x_2} 2x_1+3x_2$ instead of $\max\limits_{x_1,x_2} 2x_1+3x_2$

Comment: I guess you have to check the boundary points $(0,25)$ and $(25,0)$, but it's a little bit incomplete...

Comment: What you did is correct except that $\lambda=\pm 12$ which does not change your results. But, what happens at the "corners" : $x_1=0,x_2=25$ leads to $75$ while $x_1=25,x_2=0$ leads to $50$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1=0$ and $x_2=25$ we get a value $75$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$2x_1+3x_2\leq75$$ or
$$2x_1+3x_2\leq3(\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2})^2$$ or
$$2x_1+3x_2\leq3x_1+6\sqrt{x_1x_2}+3x_2,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

one can do the following
from $$\sqrt{x_2}=5-\sqrt{x_1}$$ we get by squaring
$$x_2=25-10\sqrt{x_1}+x_1$$ and the objective function is now
$$f(x_1)=2x_1+3(25-10\sqrt{x_1}+x_1)$$
simplifying
$$f(x_1)=5x_1-30\sqrt{x_1}+75$$
$$f'(x_1)=5-15x_1^{-1/2}$$
and $$f''(x_1)=\frac{15}{2}x_1^{-3/2}>0$$ gives a minimum

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Gives me the same answer $x_{1} = 9$ and $x_{2} = 4$. The solution says that $x_{1} = 0$ and $x_{2} = 25$.

Comment: $$x_1=0$$ is not right

Comment: solving $$5=15x_1^{-1/2}$$  gives $$x_1=\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I don' think $x_{1} = \sqrt{3}$ is correct; should be $9$.

Comment: this is a fine approach, though it give "local extrema", clearly one shall check the boundaries for $x_1$, since $x_1$ is not free: it should be chosen such that $x_2$ is positive.

Comment: @Math-fun Yes, it's a nice approach, but it doesn't answer what I was looking for. Plus the final answer is wrong.

Comment: @OGC it is not a complete answer I agree :-) - one shall, as I mentioned, look at the "crtical" points which are not only the positions where the first derivative is zero.